# Is meta_key used for ordering, filtering, or both?

Tags: wp-query

In testing I am getting inconsistent results when experimenting with the `meta_key` parameter on a fresh Wordpress install. I'm combining it with `orderby` and/or `meta_value` to understand ordering and filtering results.

**Is the `meta_key` parameter used for ordering search results as [mentioned here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) or is it used for filtering as [mentioned here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)?** In no case have I seen Wordpress use it for both features, but it would apply to one or the other inconsistently.

I am aware that I could filter by `meta_query` but that is not the scope of this question. I have examined the WP_Query->get_posts() method, and I see the exact steps used to construct the SQL (convoluted as it is) but the purpose of this question is to understand the **intended behaviour** and submit a patch if necessary.

I am testing using Wordpress version 4.9.1 (current up-to-date version), but I'm interested in all Wordpress 4.x versions and differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

Column `meta_key` is used for filtering and partially for ordering. Why partially? It is used for ordering only in combination with `meta_value`. Columns `meta_key` and `meta_value` are connected together like column `name` and column `value` in traditional table. For raw SQL select it would be possible to order posts by `meta_key` but from a practical point of view, do you order your SQL selects by column names?

Let's assume that we have custom post type `event` with `meta_key` `_speakers` and `_attendants`. I don't see point of ordering events by `meta_key` but I see point of ordering by `_speakers` value or `_attendants` value. To do this you have to make such a query.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => '_speakers',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
));
```

or

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => '_attendants',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
));
```

Comment: This answer contradicts both the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and my experimental results. The documentation states that `meta_key` is used for **filtering** when used in combination with `meta_value`. I'm not saying that you are wrong, rather that your experience is similar to mine: The docs and the results differ.

Comment: `The documentation states that meta_key is used for filtering when used in combination with meta_value`, not true. You can use `meta_key` without using `meta_value`. Example from documentation `Display posts where the custom field key is 'color', regardless of the custom field value: 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'color' ) );`, but you have to use `meta_key` and `meta_value` in order to orderby by `meta_value`.